# Monk - Where goes the data after a query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I have started using **Monk** today, and there are a few things that I don't really get, and documentation is too light.

**First here is the code:**

```
    const movieToProcess = movieCollection.findOne({ link: videoURL }).then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc)
        console.log("BLABLA")
    });
    console.log("CURSOR", typeof(movieToProcess))
```

First thing, I don't understand why the two console.log inside the promise .then() are not displaying, is that normal? If so, why?

And if this is not normal that the `console.logs` don't work, why is that?

And finally, in then, how can I get the return value of `findOne()`?

Bonus: Is there another function than `findOne()` to check if the value exist in the database?

I apologise for these questions, but there are not that much documentation for Monk.

Comment: Your promise is likely throwing an error which is why your code never reaches the ‘then’. Add a promise catch (look it up), console.log the error and see what’s up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

In your example you are setting `movieToProcess` to the value of `movieCollection.findOne()` while also calling `.then()` on it.

in your `.then`, `doc` is the return value of `findOne()`

ALSO, referring to @Geert-Jan's comment, the promise is probably being rejected and you aren't catching it.

Try this:

```
movieCollection.findOne({ link: videoURL })
  .then((doc) => {
      console.log(doc)
      console.log("BLABLA")
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
  })
```

I'll also add that `findOne()` does not return a cursor, it returns a document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still does not do anything, I don't receive any error nor value. 
I think it is because I am using the version 3.0 of mongoDB, but Monk only works for the version 2.0. So I will give up with Monk and go to Mongoose.